# android:button drawable for radiobutton not loading in emulator

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, radio-button, android-drawable

I wanted to create custom RadioButtons but I am having a problem. When I preview my work in Android Studio everything seems fine but in the emulator my drawables arent loading right.
What am I missing/doing wrong?
My Code looks like this:

XML RadioGroup:

```
    `<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/ec_radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ic_ec_switch">

    <RadioButton
        style="@style/ec_radiobuttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/it_radiobutton_sunrise"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Morgen" />

    <RadioButton
        style="@style/ec_radiobuttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/it_radiobutton_sun"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Mittag" />

    <RadioButton
        style="@style/ec_radiobuttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/it_radiobutton_sunrise"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Abend" />
</RadioGroup>`
```

XML drawable (android:button="@drawable/it_radiobutton_sunrise"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radiobutton_sunrise_active"/>
<item
    android:state_checkable="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radiobutton_sunrise_active"/>
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radiobutton_sunrise_active"/>
<item
    android:state_activated="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radiobutton_sunrise_active"/>
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radiobutton_sunrise_active"/>
<item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radiobutton_sunrise_active"/>
<item
    android:state_checked="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radiobutton_sunrise_inactive" />
<item
    android:state_checkable="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radiobutton_sunrise_inactive" />
<item
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radiobutton_sunrise_inactive" />
<item
    android:state_activated="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radiobutton_sunrise_inactive" />
<item
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radiobutton_sunrise_inactive" />
<item
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radiobutton_sunrise_inactive" />
</selector>
```

How it should look like: [image: How it should look like]
But it looks like this: [image: looks like this]

Comment: simple way `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radiobutton_sunrise_active" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radiobutton_sunrise_inactive" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>`

Comment: Unfortunately simplifying the selector xml file does not solve the problem :/

Comment: Are you being able to solve it, I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem on some older android versions , try adding this to module build.gradle .

```
    android {
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately it still doesn't work :/